# Validation input using descriptors

Tags: python

Hello I am messing around with descriptors and I am trying to understand how they work.
So this is the stupid code I am working on:

```
class InputValidator:
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value != value.lower():
            raise ValueError("Please enter lowercase letters")
        self._name = value
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self._name

class InputForm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.start()
    def start(self):
        input_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        self.name = input_name
    name = InputValidator()
INPUT = InputForm()
print(INPUT.name)
```

So if I am not mistaken that’s what descriptors should be used for, to provide some validation when an attribute is set or deleted.This is how my code should run.So first in the InputForm class we initiliaze an empty attribute self.name and then we call a function self.start().This function is going to ask the user for input and this input is going to be the value of the key “name” in the dictionary of attributes.However we want to validate this input, so we define a descriptor InputValidator which is going to check if all the letters are lowercase, in case the condition is not met a value error is raised and self.name is not succesfully saved.Now I got two questions:

1. How can I ask the user again for input (I would like to put something like `instance.start()`after raise ValueError but this is not possible).
2. Is this a good way to approach this problem, or is it just trash?In the latter case, could someone provide a professional and advanced answer(how would you go about this problem in the best way possible)
   Thank you all for your attention and help

Comment: To me grabbing a name from a user doesn't seem like a good use-case for a class definition, and checking that it is lower case doesn't seem like a good case for raising errors. Seems vaguely Java-like to make it a class.

Comment: man I am simply trying to understand how descriptors work, chill @JohnColeman

Comment: Why did you ask your second question then if you weren't interested in hearing an answer?

Comment: Ok then, first answer the first one then you can talk shit about my inexperience in the second.But the point is: How would you use a descriptor to run this program.There are many examples in the documentation that use descriptors for validation.This is surely not complex enough to make use of this concept, but I wanted to know how to correctly implement one.It’s just about it